# Can't get the option value into a hidden field

Tags: javascript, onchange, hidden

I'm using a select with options and i would like to use a form to submit the text of an option field into a database.

It's not working and I can't figure out why. the p-element changes its value (i only used it for debugging, i actually don't need it) but the hidden field stays empty.

can anybody help me out here?

```js
function GetSelectedText(){
  var e = document.getElementById("kunde");
  var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                            
  document.getElementById("title").textContent = result;
}
```

```html
<select id="kunde" name="kunde" class="form-control" onchange="GetSelectedText()">
  <option value="1">text for 1</option>
  <option value="2">text for 2</option>
  <option value="3">text for 3</option>
</select>

<p id="title">this text will be replaced</p>

<input name="title" type="hidden" id="title" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"textContent" has to be changed to "value".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since the hidden field is an input field, change `textContent` to `value`.

Also, you can't have more than one element with the SAME ID, so get rid of the P element since you don't need it anyway.

Comment: the p element was just for testing, of course i only used one element with the same id at a time. changing textcontent to value was the answer, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your `p` element has the same ID as the `input` element. HTML specifies that an ID must be unique. Something like this would work:

```
<p id="title">this text will be replaced</p>
<input name="title" type="hidden" id="titleInput" value="">
```

And the javascript:

```
// [...] rest of the function
document.getElementById("title").textContent = result;
document.getElementById("titleInput").value = result;
```